# Excel won't recognize timestamp in format of "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time, date, timestamp

I have a column of timestamps (strings) formatted like so:

[image: timestamps]

This can be deduced to the following format: `m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM`

I'm trying to get them to be formatted into dates but Excel refuses for some reason. I've tried:

1. `DATE()`
2. `DATEVALUE()`
3. `* 1`.  `/ 1`, etc.

All to no avail. I'm surprised Excel can't pick this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

`LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)` extracts the date (`1-14-2019`)
If your usual date format is like that, wrapping the previous result in `DATEVALUE` should work.

---

If the previous doesn't work, the following must do it:

```
=DATE(
    MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,4)+1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-FIND("-",A1,4)-1),
    LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1),
    MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND("-",A1,4)-FIND("-",A1)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `-` the Eacel expects the format to be `yyyy-mm-dd` with `m-d-yy` all we need to do is to substitute the `-` for `/`:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","/")
```

Then format as desired.  It will keep the full date/time.

If Date is the only thing wanted then:

```
=INT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","/"))
```

And format as desired.